# ipairs loop always returning just one of the values in lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

Quick edit: _G.i is the 1 - 24 table I set to create a 24 hour time frame. It's globally stored in a tertiary script and implemented like this:

```
_G.i = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}
```

So I'm trying to get this loop to work with a day/night cycle I have created. I want the loop to constantly check what time it is and print that time to the console based on a few parameters I set.

```
light = script.Parent.lightPart.lightCone
timeofday = ""
wait(1)

function checkTime()
    for i, v in ipairs(_G.i) do
        wait(1)
        print(v)
        print(timeofday)
        if v > 20 and v < 6 then
            timeofday = "night"
        else
            timeofday = "day"
        end 
    end
end  

while true do
    checkTime()
    wait(1)
end
```

For some reason, this is only printing day in the console even though I have it looping properly. The times are matched with the same of those in the day-night script. I'll post that here as well.

```
function changeTime()
    for i, v in ipairs(_G.i) do
        game.Lighting:SetMinutesAfterMidnight(v * 60)
        wait(1)
    end
end

while true do
    changeTime()
end
```

Sorry if this post is sloppy or the code is sloppy I'm new to both. Have been trying to figure this out on my own, and been doing good on it originally I had no clue what a ipairs loops was but I managed to get it working with the day night cycle instead of a infinite wait(1) loop.

Comment: can you include the code where you populate `_G.i`?

Comment: Yea, really simple this is all that script contains `_G.i = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is the line:

```
if v > 20 and v < 6 then
```

`v` can never be *both* greater than 20 and less than 6. You need the `or` logical operator.

Beyond that, I'm not sure why you are using the global `i` to hold a list of the numbers 1 through 24? You can achieve the same affect with a [ranging for loop](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html). Also, if you are trying to check the current time set by your lower code, then you should store the time value in a global variable. Like so:

```
light = script.Parent.lightPart.lightCone
current_time = 0

function checkTime()
    print(current_time)
    if current_time > 20 or current_time < 6 then
        timeofday = "night"
    else
        timeofday = "day"
    end 
    print(timeofday)
end  

while true do
    checkTime()
    wait(0.1)
end


function changeTime()
    for v = 1, 24 do
        game.Lighting:SetMinutesAfterMidnight(v * 60)
        current_time = v
    end
end

while true do
    changeTime()
    wait(1)
end
```

The issue with the way you were doing it is that you assume that the `checkTime()` function will always run after the `changeTime()` function, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Thanks very much! I knew it was something to do with that line but I was so deep in trying to figure it out I let simple logic slip through my mind. I also am going to add in the simpler loop as it'll probably help me later on. Thanks!